# How to extract input into 3 var from example(23/11/2020) using cin.get or get.line

Tags: c++, cin

I tried to use cin.get with delimiter but the cin seems to get flushed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char date[2], month[2], year[4];
    cin.getline(date, 3 ,'/');
    cin.getline(month, 3 ,'/');
    cout << date <<month;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

It shows month first in the output not date.

Comment: You have not allocated enough space to store 2 characters and a nul terminator. Try 3 & 5 instead of 2 & 4. You don't need to exactly match the size either. I'd allocate 8 characters for each and be done with it knowing I wouldn't have an overflow.

Comment: What makes you think you can give `getline` a buffer of size 2 and tell it that it can write up to 3 characters into it?  Your program has undefined behavior.  Most likely the null terminator from overflowing `month` overwrites the first character in `date`, assuming your program hasn't already exploded at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by incrementing array size by 1, 1 is for null terminator but better approach would be,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

void parse_date(std::string date, int &day, int &month, int &year)
{
    std::stringstream stream(date);
    
    stream>>day;
    stream.ignore();
    stream>>month;
    stream.ignore();
    stream>>year;
}

int main()
{
    std::string date;
    int day   = 0;
    int month = 0;
    int year  = 0;
    
    std::cout << "Enter Date  : ";
    std::cin  >> date;

    parse_date(date, day, month, year);
    
    std::cout << "Parsed Date : ";
    std::cout << day << '-' << month << '-' << year;
    
    return 0;
}
```